# Run failed: User program failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amlrun' in Azure ML Experiment

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using VS Code to submit a Machine Learning experiment in Azure Portal. When running the experiment I'm obtaining the following error:

Run failed: User program failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amlrun'

This is the code structure:

.vscode (json configuration file)

aml_config

scripts

----- amlrun.py (a script with some functions)

----- model_training.py (a script creating and saving the model)

This is the configuration file:

```
{
    "script": "model_training.py",
    "framework": "Python",
    "communicator": "None",
    "target": "testazure",
    "environment": {
        "python": {
            "userManagedDependencies": false,
            "condaDependencies": {
                "dependencies": [
                    "python=3.6.2",
                    "scikit-learn",
                    "numpy",
                    "pandas",
                    {
                        "pip": [
                            "azureml-defaults"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "docker": {
            "baseImage": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:0.2.4",
            "enabled": true,
            "baseImageRegistry": {
                "address": null,
                "username": null,
                "password": null
            }
        }
    },
    "history": {
        "outputCollection": true,
        "snapshotProject": false,
        "directoriesToWatch": [
            "logs"
        ]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your training script is running in azure, it's not able to find all your local imports i.e. `amlrun.py` script.

The submitted training job to azure builds a docker image with your files first and runs the experiment; but in this case the extension hasn't included `amlrun.py`.

This is probably because when you have submit the training job with the extension, the visual studio code window opened is not pointing to be in `scripts` folder.

Taken from one of the replies to a [previously raised github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24032):

> The extension currently requires the script you are working on to be
>   in the folder that is open in VS Code and not in a sub-directory.

---

To fix this you can do **either** of the following:

1. You would need to re-open Visual Studio Code in `scripts` folder instead of parent directory.
2. Move all files in `script` directory to be in it's parent directory.

---

If you're looking for more flexible way to submit training jobs and managing aml - you can use the [azure machine learning sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/intro?view=azure-ml-py) for python.

Some examples of using the SDK to manage expirements can be found in the links below:

1. [Scikit Learn Model Training Docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml.md)
2. [Basic Pytorch Model Training and Deployment Example Repo](https://github.com/rithinch/heartfulness-similar-content-service)

Comment: @DiogoSantos, glad that it's solved. And if my answer is helpful, could you please help up vote & mark it? Thanks :)

Comment: I've already marked it as correct but since I have less the 15 in reputation, my upvote doesn't count. Thanks once more :)